# WSO2 Carbon Core 4.2.0 Patch 10 build failed

Tags: maven, patch, wso2

I checkout patch 10 (Carbon Core 4.2.0) from

https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/branches/4.2.0/patches/patch0010/core/org.wso2.carbon.core/4.2.0

and when I want to build it I get this error.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project org.wso2.carbon.core: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] WSO2_Carbon_4.2.0\patches\patch0010\core\org.wso2.carbon.core\4.2.0\src\main\java\org\wso2\carbon\core\clustering\hazelcast\HazelcastClusteringAgent.java:[24,27] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] WSO2_Carbon_4.2.0\patches\patch0010\core\org.wso2.carbon.core\4.2.0\src\main\java\org\wso2\carbon\core\clustering\hazelcast\aws\AWSBasedMembershipScheme.java:[26,25] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] WSO2_Carbon_4.2.0\patches\patch0010\core\org.wso2.carbon.core\4.2.0\src\main\java\org\wso2\carbon\core\clustering\hazelcast\aws\AWSBasedMembershipScheme.java:[155,43] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] WSO2_Carbon_4.2.0\patches\patch0010\core\org.wso2.carbon.core\4.2.0\src\main\java\org\wso2\carbon\core\clustering\hazelcast\wka\WKABasedMembershipScheme.java:[27,25] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] WSO2_Carbon_4.2.0\patches\patch0010\core\org.wso2.carbon.core\4.2.0\src\main\java\org\wso2\carbon\core\clustering\hazelcast\wka\WKABasedMembershipScheme.java:[29,25] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] WSO2_Carbon_4.2.0\patches\patch0010\core\org.wso2.carbon.core\4.2.0\src\main\java\org\wso2\carbon\core\clustering\hazelcast\wka\WKABasedMembershipScheme.java:[178,43] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] WSO2_Carbon_4.2.0\patches\patch0010\core\org.wso2.carbon.core\4.2.0\src\main\java\org\wso2\carbon\core\clustering\hazelcast\wka\WKABasedMembershipScheme.java:[208,31] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] WSO2_Carbon_4.2.0\patches\patch0010\core\org.wso2.carbon.core\4.2.0\src\main\java\org\wso2\carbon\core\clustering\hazelcast\wka\WKABasedMembershipScheme.java:[213,31] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] WSO2_Carbon_4.2.0\patches\patch0010\core\org.wso2.carbon.core\4.2.0\src\main\java\org\wso2\carbon\core\clustering\hazelcast\HazelcastDistributedMapProvider.java:[24,25] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] WSO2_Carbon_4.2.0\patches\patch0010\core\org.wso2.carbon.core\4.2.0\src\main\java\org\wso2\carbon\core\clustering\hazelcast\HazelcastGroupManagementAgent.java:[32,25] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] WSO2_Carbon_4.2.0\patches\patch0010\core\org.wso2.carbon.core\4.2.0\src\main\java\org\wso2\carbon\core\clustering\hazelcast\HazelcastGroupManagementAgent.java:[34,25] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] WSO2_Carbon_4.2.0\patches\patch0010\core\org.wso2.carbon.core\4.2.0\src\main\java\org\wso2\carbon\core\clustering\hazelcast\HazelcastGroupManagementAgent.java:[205,43] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] WSO2_Carbon_4.2.0\patches\patch0010\core\org.wso2.carbon.core\4.2.0\src\main\java\org\wso2\carbon\core\clustering\hazelcast\HazelcastGroupManagementAgent.java:[237,31] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] WSO2_Carbon_4.2.0\patches\patch0010\core\org.wso2.carbon.core\4.2.0\src\main\java\org\wso2\carbon\core\clustering\hazelcast\HazelcastGroupManagementAgent.java:[242,31] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] WSO2_Carbon_4.2.0\patches\patch0010\core\org.wso2.carbon.core\4.2.0\src\main\java\org\wso2\carbon\core\clustering\hazelcast\multicast\MulticastBasedMembershipScheme.java:[24,25] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] WSO2_Carbon_4.2.0\patches\patch0010\core\org.wso2.carbon.core\4.2.0\src\main\java\org\wso2\carbon\core\clustering\hazelcast\multicast\MulticastBasedMembershipScheme.java:[144,43] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] WSO2_Carbon_4.2.0\patches\patch0010\core\org.wso2.carbon.core\4.2.0\src\main\java\org\wso2\carbon\core\clustering\hazelcast\HazelcastClusteringAgent.java:[150,40] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] WSO2_Carbon_4.2.0\patches\patch0010\core\org.wso2.carbon.core\4.2.0\src\main\java\org\wso2\carbon\core\clustering\hazelcast\wka\WKABasedMembershipScheme.java:[177,8] error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] WSO2_Carbon_4.2.0\patches\patch0010\core\org.wso2.carbon.core\4.2.0\src\main\java\org\wso2\carbon\core\clustering\hazelcast\wka\WKABasedMembershipScheme.java:[207,8] error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] WSO2_Carbon_4.2.0\patches\patch0010\core\org.wso2.carbon.core\4.2.0\src\main\java\org\wso2\carbon\core\clustering\hazelcast\wka\WKABasedMembershipScheme.java:[212,8] error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] WSO2_Carbon_4.2.0\patches\patch0010\core\org.wso2.carbon.core\4.2.0\src\main\java\org\wso2\carbon\core\clustering\hazelcast\HazelcastDistributedMapProvider.java:[100,43] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] WSO2_Carbon_4.2.0\patches\patch0010\core\org.wso2.carbon.core\4.2.0\src\main\java\org\wso2\carbon\core\clustering\hazelcast\HazelcastDistributedMapProvider.java:[105,43] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] WSO2_Carbon_4.2.0\patches\patch0010\core\org.wso2.carbon.core\4.2.0\src\main\java\org\wso2\carbon\core\clustering\hazelcast\HazelcastDistributedMapProvider.java:[101,27] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] WSO2_Carbon_4.2.0\patches\patch0010\core\org.wso2.carbon.core\4.2.0\src\main\java\org\wso2\carbon\core\clustering\hazelcast\HazelcastDistributedMapProvider.java:[99,20] error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] WSO2_Carbon_4.2.0\patches\patch0010\core\org.wso2.carbon.core\4.2.0\src\main\java\org\wso2\carbon\core\clustering\hazelcast\HazelcastDistributedMapProvider.java:[104,20] error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] WSO2_Carbon_4.2.0\patches\patch0010\core\org.wso2.carbon.core\4.2.0\src\main\java\org\wso2\carbon\core\clustering\hazelcast\HazelcastGroupManagementAgent.java:[236,8] error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] WSO2_Carbon_4.2.0\patches\patch0010\core\org.wso2.carbon.core\4.2.0\src\main\java\org\wso2\carbon\core\clustering\hazelcast\HazelcastGroupManagementAgent.java:[241,8] error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] WSO2_Carbon_4.2.0\patches\patch0010\core\org.wso2.carbon.core\4.2.0\src\main\java\org\wso2\carbon\core\clustering\hazelcast\multicast\MulticastBasedMembershipScheme.java:[143,8] error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] WSO2_Carbon_4.2.0\patches\patch0010\core\org.wso2.carbon.core\4.2.0\src\main\java\org\wso2\carbon\core\multitenancy\transports\TenantTransportSender.java:[88,69] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] WSO2_Carbon_4.2.0\patches\patch0010\core\org.wso2.carbon.core\4.2.0\src\main\java\org\wso2\carbon\core\multitenancy\transports\TenantTransportSender.java:[89,59] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] WSO2_Carbon_4.2.0\patches\patch0010\core\org.wso2.carbon.core\4.2.0\src\main\java\org\wso2\carbon\core\multitenancy\transports\TenantTransportSender.java:[124,69] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] WSO2_Carbon_4.2.0\patches\patch0010\core\org.wso2.carbon.core\4.2.0\src\main\java\org\wso2\carbon\core\multitenancy\transports\TenantTransportSender.java:[125,59] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] WSO2_Carbon_4.2.0\patches\patch0010\core\org.wso2.carbon.core\4.2.0\src\main\java\org\wso2\carbon\core\multitenancy\transports\TenantTransportSender.java:[126,69] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] WSO2_Carbon_4.2.0\patches\patch0010\core\org.wso2.carbon.core\4.2.0\src\main\java\org\wso2\carbon\core\multitenancy\transports\TenantTransportSender.java:[127,59] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] WSO2_Carbon_4.2.0\patches\patch0010\core\org.wso2.carbon.core\4.2.0\src\main\java\org\wso2\carbon\core\multitenancy\transports\TenantTransportSender.java:[132,63] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] WSO2_Carbon_4.2.0\patches\patch0010\core\org.wso2.carbon.core\4.2.0\src\main\java\org\wso2\carbon\core\multitenancy\transports\TenantTransportSender.java:[133,73] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] WSO2_Carbon_4.2.0\patches\patch0010\core\org.wso2.carbon.core\4.2.0\src\main\java\org\wso2\carbon\core\multitenancy\transports\TenantTransportSender.java:[134,52] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] WSO2_Carbon_4.2.0\patches\patch0010\core\org.wso2.carbon.core\4.2.0\src\main\java\org\wso2\carbon\core\multitenancy\transports\TenantTransportSender.java:[137,83] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] WSO2_Carbon_4.2.0\patches\patch0010\core\org.wso2.carbon.core\4.2.0\src\main\java\org\wso2\carbon\core\multitenancy\transports\TenantTransportSender.java:[138,82] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] WSO2_Carbon_4.2.0\patches\patch0010\core\org.wso2.carbon.core\4.2.0\src\main\java\org\wso2\carbon\core\multitenancy\transports\TenantTransportSender.java:[141,69] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] WSO2_Carbon_4.2.0\patches\patch0010\core\org.wso2.carbon.core\4.2.0\src\main\java\org\wso2\carbon\core\multitenancy\transports\TenantTransportSender.java:[143,69] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] WSO2_Carbon_4.2.0\patches\patch0010\core\org.wso2.carbon.core\4.2.0\src\main\java\org\wso2\carbon\core\multitenancy\transports\TenantTransportSender.java:[185,55] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] WSO2_Carbon_4.2.0\patches\patch0010\core\org.wso2.carbon.core\4.2.0\src\main\java\org\wso2\carbon\core\multitenancy\transports\TenantTransportSender.java:[186,73] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] WSO2_Carbon_4.2.0\patches\patch0010\core\org.wso2.carbon.core\4.2.0\src\main\java\org\wso2\carbon\core\multitenancy\transports\TenantTransportSender.java:[187,63] error: cannot find symbol
```

I found out that this patch uses **hazelcust-3.0.1.wso2v1.jar** and this jar doesn't conatin a few important classes. So, how WSO2 developers build this patch?

Also, in patch 009 and 007 is the same problem, but other classes are missing.
How I can build this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout all patches from 0001 to 0010 from [here](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/branches/4.2.0/patches/). Then build all from 0001 to 0010 in that order (this sequence is important since there are dependencies).